# Why does the `then()` handler of a promise execute immediately?

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to learn more thoroughly how promises work in JavaScript and I tried the following code:

```
function delay(timeout) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(resolve,timeout);
    });
}

var promise = delay(10000);
promise.then(alert('after delay'));
```

I wanted to write a wrapper for the JavaScript `setTimeout()` function and I assume `alert` should execute after 10 seconds. However, this code shows it immediately.

Could someone explain what is wrong here?

Comment: It's your `alert` that executes immediately, not the promise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> promise.then(alert('after delay'));
> ```

Here you:

1. Call `alert()`
2. Pass its return value to `then()`

So the promise doesn't resolve immediately. You just `alert` before it resolves.

You have to pass a **function** to `then`.

```
promise.then(alert.bind(window, 'after delay'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `function` to your `then` statement:

```
promise.then(function(){
    alert('after delay')
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is explain by [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42903322/1960455). An additional solution would be using arrow functions:

```
promise.then(() => alert('after delay'));
```