# JS Syncronous alert function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sequential

I have been searching for so long, time to ask for help...

What I am trying to do is just to show an `alert()` after another function has finished executing. The part I am referring to is the `success` of the `ajax` call.

```
jQuery(document).on('click','a.remove_from_cart',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  startWait();
  var self = jQuery(this);
  jQuery.ajax({
    url:ajaxurl,
    type:'post',
    cache:false,
    data:{
      action: self.data('action'),
      post_id: self.data('id'),
      nonce: self.data('nonce')
    },
    success:function(data){
      if (data) {
        // some action
      }
      // please help me here
      stopWait().then(alert(data));
    }
  });
});
```

`startWait()` and `stopWait()` are two functions that just add/remove classes from 2 html elements:

```
function startWait() {
  document.getElementById('wait').classList.add('active');
  document.body.classList.add('wait');
}
function stopWait() {
  var d = jQuery.Deferred();
  document.getElementById('wait').classList.remove('active');
  document.body.classList.remove('wait');
  return d.promise();
}
```

They just show/hide an overlay with a spinner inside.

In the `success` method of the `ajax` call I would like to first `stopWait()` aka hide the overlay, then alert some info.
I tried callbacks, promises, jQuery deferred and I can't remember what else, I just can not make this work, always, first the `alert()` gets shown then only after I close the `alert(data)` the `stopWait()` does its job. Why?

Please can you help me understand what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks!

**EDIT 1:** wrapping the alert() inside a function does not solve the issue. Now the stopWait() gets executed but then no alert is shown. Please check the codepen: https://codepen.io/usainicola/pen/GxOzqz

**EDIT 2:** issue solved, here the working codepen: https://codepen.io/usainicola/pen/MVORyd

Comment: `stopWait().then(function () { alert(data) });`

Comment: You have to wrap the `alert()` in a *function* to be called. Your code now is passing the return value of `alert()` to `.then()`.

Comment: And there's no reason to code `stopWait()` with a Promise like that; its code is synchronous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my promise executes immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903253/why-my-promise-executes-immediately)

Comment: Thanks, I tried stopWait().then(function () { alert(data) }); but now the alert does not get shown after the stopWait() has executed

Comment: I created a codepen, there you can see that wrapping the alert inside a function does not solve the issue, the stopWait() gets executed but the alert not anymore:

https://codepen.io/usainicola/pen/GxOzqz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to resolve the promise before returning it like

```
function stopWait() {
 var d = $.Deferred();
 document.getElementById("wait").classList.remove("active");
 d.resolve();
 return d.promise();
}
```

please take a look of changed codepen
[edited code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVOxmG)